# Why isn't tkinter updating the percentage completion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a chess game in tkinter with an ai. Now, in my ai I have done the following (an excerpt of my total code):

```
global chess_board
length = len(total_moves)

for index, move in enumerate(total_moves):
    chess_board.percentage_label.config(text="Completion = {}".format(
        int((index + 1) / length) * 100))
    chess_board.update()
```

This is in my chessAi class and chess_board is an instance of my chessBoard class. However, tkinter waits until the end of the loop and the only two percentages displayed are 0 and 100. How can I remedy this?

Comment: Is `chess_board` running in its own thread?

Comment: How can I tell?

Comment: You would have had to set up threading yourself.  One possible issue is that the computations you are running is blocking the UI updates.  Creating a separate thread for the UI is one way to manage that.

Comment: tinter doesn't support animations and constant or quick updating of widgets, it waits till everything is done to update, You can use the `canvas` widget to display animations or a loading percentage that updates constantly.

Comment: Thanks @Flaming_Dorito it works now. I don't know how to do threading.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter won’t be able anything while you are in a function.
To remedy this you can use a Thread but it would not be elegant.
I would use the after method of tkinter widgets like this :

```
def display(index):
    move = total_moves[index]
    [your code]
    chess_board.percentage_label.after(0.01, lamda: display(index+1))
```

Comment: Putting the percentage_labep in a Canvas worked but thanks for the advice.